# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} for new site

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, joomla3.0

I have a really old Joomla-1.0 site with tens of thousands of articles that we recently upgraded to a current version of Joomla with SEF. This is on apache-2.4.34 on fedora29.

The problem is that it doesn't support the old URL format any longer, so I'm trying to rewrite many of the old URL formats to work with the site.

The one I'm having the most difficulty with contains a query string:

```
example.com/index.php?option=login
```

This should redirect to example.com/register

My rewrite rules are not working, however:

```
# /index.php?option=login
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=login$
RewriteRule ^/index.php$      https://linuxsecurity.com/register       [R=301,L,QSD]
```

This is placed in the .htaccess file in the document root. I've also tried placing it in a  section within the virtual domain config.

It appears it's being ignored entirely. It reports an error like "Component not found", as if it's being interpreted by joomla.

I also have several other RewriteRule entries below that don't appear to work. They just report 404 pages. If I enter the article IDs into the replacement link, it works fine.

```
RewriteRule ^/content/view/([^/]+)              /index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'd appreciate any advice you may be able to provide.

Comment: Remove the starting slash, write relative to current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is good, but need to tweak the rule for the login one.  Please try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=login$
RewriteRule ^(.*)  https://linuxsecurity.com/register  [R=301,L,QSD]
```

For the other content redirects, this is what I have used for Joomla 1.0 to Joomla 3.x before:

```
RewriteRule ^content/view/(.*)$ /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

https://www.yellowwebmonkey.com/developer-blog/item/redirect-joomla-1-0-sef-links-for-joomla-3-x